# Paraview python script not saving csv file during automation

Tags: python, csv, automation, paraview, openfoam

I would to like automate the plot over line filter with three cases (having different grid size).I started “start trace” in paraview and all the actions are recorded in a python script. When I run "pvbatch" command, I could get plot1.csv only in last folder (i.e. case_3) but not in all three folders.

Could anyone please let me know why this script is not saving csv file in all folders. ?

Thank you very much

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'   
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()
l=["case_1","case_2","case_3"]
for i in l:
    # create a new 'Legacy VTK Reader'
     case_1_0vtk = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames ['/media/skumar/Official/OF/SK/grids/testing/'+i+'/VTK/'+i+'_0.vtk'])

# get active view
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
# uncomment following to set a specific view size     
# renderView1.ViewSize = [1004, 490]

# show data in view
case_1_0vtkDisplay = Show(case_1_0vtk, renderView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
case_1_0vtkDisplay.Representation = 'Surface'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.ColorArrayName = [None, '']
case_1_0vtkDisplay.OSPRayScaleArray = 'AR'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.OSPRayScaleFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.SelectOrientationVectors = 'AR'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.ScaleFactor = 0.020000000298023225
case_1_0vtkDisplay.SelectScaleArray = 'AR'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.GlyphType = 'Arrow'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.GlyphTableIndexArray = 'AR'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.DataAxesGrid = 'GridAxesRepresentation'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.PolarAxes = 'PolarAxesRepresentation'
case_1_0vtkDisplay.ScalarOpacityUnitDistance = 0.004056509360095651

# reset view to fit data
renderView1.ResetCamera()

# update the view to ensure updated data information
renderView1.Update()

# set scalar coloring
ColorBy(case_1_0vtkDisplay, ('POINTS', 'Ma'))

# rescale color and/or opacity maps used to include current data range
case_1_0vtkDisplay.RescaleTransferFunctionToDataRange(True, False)

# show color bar/color legend
case_1_0vtkDisplay.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView1, True)

# get color transfer function/color map for 'Ma'
maLUT = GetColorTransferFunction('Ma')

# create a new 'Slice'
slice1 = Slice(Input=case_1_0vtk)
slice1.SliceType = 'Plane'
slice1.SliceOffsetValues = [0.0]

# init the 'Plane' selected for 'SliceType'
slice1.SliceType.Origin = [0.10000000149011612, 0.022600000258535147, 0.0005000000237487257]

# toggle 3D widget visibility (only when running from the GUI)
Hide3DWidgets(proxy=slice1.SliceType)

# Properties modified on slice1.SliceType
slice1.SliceType.Origin = [0.100000001490116, 0.0226000002585351, 0.000500000023748726]
slice1.SliceType.Normal = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

# Properties modified on slice1.SliceType
slice1.SliceType.Origin = [0.100000001490116, 0.0226000002585351, 0.000500000023748726]
slice1.SliceType.Normal = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

# show data in view
slice1Display = Show(slice1, renderView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
slice1Display.Representation = 'Surface'
slice1Display.ColorArrayName = ['POINTS', 'Ma']
slice1Display.LookupTable = maLUT
slice1Display.OSPRayScaleArray = 'AR'
slice1Display.OSPRayScaleFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
slice1Display.SelectOrientationVectors = 'AR'
slice1Display.ScaleFactor = 0.020000000298023225
slice1Display.SelectScaleArray = 'AR'
slice1Display.GlyphType = 'Arrow'
slice1Display.GlyphTableIndexArray = 'AR'
slice1Display.DataAxesGrid = 'GridAxesRepresentation'
slice1Display.PolarAxes = 'PolarAxesRepresentation'

# hide data in view
Hide(case_1_0vtk, renderView1)

# show color bar/color legend
slice1Display.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView1, True)

# update the view to ensure updated data information
renderView1.Update()

# create a new 'Plot Over Line'
plotOverLine1 = PlotOverLine(Input=slice1,
    Source='High Resolution Line Source')

# init the 'High Resolution Line Source' selected for 'Source'
plotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [0.0, -0.004800000227987766, 0.0005000000237487257]
plotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [0.20000000298023224, 0.05000000074505806, 0.0005000000237487257]

# Properties modified on plotOverLine1.Source
plotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [0.100000001490116, -0.0, 0.000500000023748726]
plotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [0.100000001490116, 0.0500000007450581, 0.000500000023748726]

# Properties modified on plotOverLine1
plotOverLine1.Tolerance = 2.22044604925031e-16

# Properties modified on plotOverLine1.Source
plotOverLine1.Source.Point1 = [0.100000001490116, -0.0, 0.000500000023748726]
plotOverLine1.Source.Point2 = [0.100000001490116, 0.0500000007450581, 0.000500000023748726]

# show data in view
plotOverLine1Display = Show(plotOverLine1, renderView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
plotOverLine1Display.Representation = 'Surface'
plotOverLine1Display.ColorArrayName = ['POINTS', 'Ma']
plotOverLine1Display.LookupTable = maLUT
plotOverLine1Display.OSPRayScaleArray = 'AR'
plotOverLine1Display.OSPRayScaleFunction = 'PiecewiseFunction'
plotOverLine1Display.SelectOrientationVectors = 'AR'
plotOverLine1Display.ScaleFactor = 0.005000000074505806
plotOverLine1Display.SelectScaleArray = 'AR'
plotOverLine1Display.GlyphType = 'Arrow'
plotOverLine1Display.GlyphTableIndexArray = 'AR'
plotOverLine1Display.DataAxesGrid = 'GridAxesRepresentation'
plotOverLine1Display.PolarAxes = 'PolarAxesRepresentation'

# Create a new 'Line Chart View'
lineChartView1 = CreateView('XYChartView')
lineChartView1.ViewSize = [497, 490]

# get layout
layout1 = GetLayout()

# place view in the layout
#layout1.AssignView(2, lineChartView1)

# show data in view
plotOverLine1Display_1 = Show(plotOverLine1, lineChartView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
plotOverLine1Display_1.CompositeDataSetIndex = [0]
plotOverLine1Display_1.UseIndexForXAxis = 0
plotOverLine1Display_1.XArrayName = 'arc_length'
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesVisibility = ['alphat', 'AR', 'cellID', 'H', 'H2', 'H2O', 'H2O2', 'HO2', 'k', 'Ma', 'N2', 'nut', 'O', 'O2', 'OH', 'omega', 'p', 'Qdot', 'rho', 'T', 'U_Magnitude']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLabel = ['alphat', 'alphat', 'AR', 'AR', 'arc_length', 'arc_length', 'cellID', 'cellID', 'H', 'H', 'H2', 'H2', 'H2O', 'H2O', 'H2O2', 'H2O2', 'HO2', 'HO2', 'k', 'k', 'Ma', 'Ma', 'N2', 'N2', 'nut', 'nut', 'O', 'O', 'O2', 'O2', 'OH', 'OH', 'omega', 'omega', 'p', 'p', 'Qdot', 'Qdot', 'rho', 'rho', 'T', 'T', 'U_X', 'U_X', 'U_Y', 'U_Y', 'U_Z', 'U_Z', 'U_Magnitude', 'U_Magnitude', 'vtkValidPointMask', 'vtkValidPointMask', 'Points_X', 'Points_X', 'Points_Y', 'Points_Y', 'Points_Z', 'Points_Z', 'Points_Magnitude', 'Points_Magnitude']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesColor = ['alphat', '0', '0', '0', 'AR', '0.89', '0.1', '0.11', 'arc_length', '0.22', '0.49', '0.72', 'cellID', '0.3', '0.69', '0.29', 'H', '0.6', '0.31', '0.64', 'H2', '1', '0.5', '0', 'H2O', '0.65', '0.34', '0.16', 'H2O2', '0', '0', '0', 'HO2', '0.89', '0.1', '0.11', 'k', '0.22', '0.49', '0.72', 'Ma', '0.3', '0.69', '0.29', 'N2', '0.6', '0.31', '0.64', 'nut', '1', '0.5', '0', 'O', '0.65', '0.34', '0.16', 'O2', '0', '0', '0', 'OH', '0.89', '0.1', '0.11', 'omega', '0.22', '0.49', '0.72', 'p', '0.3', '0.69', '0.29', 'Qdot', '0.6', '0.31', '0.64', 'rho', '1', '0.5', '0', 'T', '0.65', '0.34', '0.16', 'U_X', '0', '0', '0', 'U_Y', '0.89', '0.1', '0.11', 'U_Z', '0.22', '0.49', '0.72', 'U_Magnitude', '0.3', '0.69', '0.29', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0.6', '0.31', '0.64', 'Points_X', '1', '0.5', '0', 'Points_Y', '0.65', '0.34', '0.16', 'Points_Z', '0', '0', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0.89', '0.1', '0.11']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesPlotCorner = ['alphat', '0', 'AR', '0', 'arc_length', '0', 'cellID', '0', 'H', '0', 'H2', '0', 'H2O', '0', 'H2O2', '0', 'HO2', '0', 'k', '0', 'Ma', '0', 'N2', '0', 'nut', '0', 'O', '0', 'O2', '0', 'OH', '0', 'omega', '0', 'p', '0', 'Qdot', '0', 'rho', '0', 'T', '0', 'U_X', '0', 'U_Y', '0', 'U_Z', '0', 'U_Magnitude', '0', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0', 'Points_X', '0', 'Points_Y', '0', 'Points_Z', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLabelPrefix = ''
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLineStyle = ['alphat', '1', 'AR', '1', 'arc_length', '1', 'cellID', '1', 'H', '1', 'H2', '1', 'H2O', '1', 'H2O2', '1', 'HO2', '1', 'k', '1', 'Ma', '1', 'N2', '1', 'nut', '1', 'O', '1', 'O2', '1', 'OH', '1', 'omega', '1', 'p', '1', 'Qdot', '1', 'rho', '1', 'T', '1', 'U_X', '1', 'U_Y', '1', 'U_Z', '1', 'U_Magnitude', '1', 'vtkValidPointMask', '1', 'Points_X', '1', 'Points_Y', '1', 'Points_Z', '1', 'Points_Magnitude', '1']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLineThickness = ['alphat', '2', 'AR', '2', 'arc_length', '2', 'cellID', '2', 'H', '2', 'H2', '2', 'H2O', '2', 'H2O2', '2', 'HO2', '2', 'k', '2', 'Ma', '2', 'N2', '2', 'nut', '2', 'O', '2', 'O2', '2', 'OH', '2', 'omega', '2', 'p', '2', 'Qdot', '2', 'rho', '2', 'T', '2', 'U_X', '2', 'U_Y', '2', 'U_Z', '2', 'U_Magnitude', '2', 'vtkValidPointMask', '2', 'Points_X', '2', 'Points_Y', '2', 'Points_Z', '2', 'Points_Magnitude', '2']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesMarkerStyle = ['alphat', '0', 'AR', '0', 'arc_length', '0', 'cellID', '0', 'H', '0', 'H2', '0', 'H2O', '0', 'H2O2', '0', 'HO2', '0', 'k', '0', 'Ma', '0', 'N2', '0', 'nut', '0', 'O', '0', 'O2', '0', 'OH', '0', 'omega', '0', 'p', '0', 'Qdot', '0', 'rho', '0', 'T', '0', 'U_X', '0', 'U_Y', '0', 'U_Z', '0', 'U_Magnitude', '0', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0', 'Points_X', '0', 'Points_Y', '0', 'Points_Z', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0']

# update the view to ensure updated data information
renderView1.Update()

# update the view to ensure updated data information
lineChartView1.Update()

# Properties modified on plotOverLine1Display_1
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesVisibility = []
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesColor = ['alphat', '0', '0', '0', 'AR', '0.889998', '0.100008', '0.110002', 'arc_length', '0.220005', '0.489998', '0.719997', 'cellID', '0.300008', '0.689998', '0.289998', 'H', '0.6', '0.310002', '0.639994', 'H2', '1', '0.500008', '0', 'H2O', '0.650004', '0.340002', '0.160006', 'H2O2', '0', '0', '0', 'HO2', '0.889998', '0.100008', '0.110002', 'k', '0.220005', '0.489998', '0.719997', 'Ma', '0.300008', '0.689998', '0.289998', 'N2', '0.6', '0.310002', '0.639994', 'nut', '1', '0.500008', '0', 'O', '0.650004', '0.340002', '0.160006', 'O2', '0', '0', '0', 'OH', '0.889998', '0.100008', '0.110002', 'omega', '0.220005', '0.489998', '0.719997', 'p', '0.300008', '0.689998', '0.289998', 'Qdot', '0.6', '0.310002', '0.639994', 'rho', '1', '0.500008', '0', 'T', '0.650004', '0.340002', '0.160006', 'U_X', '0', '0', '0', 'U_Y', '0.889998', '0.100008', '0.110002', 'U_Z', '0.220005', '0.489998', '0.719997', 'U_Magnitude', '0.300008', '0.689998', '0.289998', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0.6', '0.310002', '0.639994', 'Points_X', '1', '0.500008', '0', 'Points_Y', '0.650004', '0.340002', '0.160006', 'Points_Z', '0', '0', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0.889998', '0.100008', '0.110002']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesPlotCorner = ['AR', '0', 'H', '0', 'H2', '0', 'H2O', '0', 'H2O2', '0', 'HO2', '0', 'Ma', '0', 'N2', '0', 'O', '0', 'O2', '0', 'OH', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0', 'Points_X', '0', 'Points_Y', '0', 'Points_Z', '0', 'Qdot', '0', 'T', '0', 'U_Magnitude', '0', 'U_X', '0', 'U_Y', '0', 'U_Z', '0', 'alphat', '0', 'arc_length', '0', 'cellID', '0', 'k', '0', 'nut', '0', 'omega', '0', 'p', '0', 'rho', '0', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLineStyle = ['AR', '1', 'H', '1', 'H2', '1', 'H2O', '1', 'H2O2', '1', 'HO2', '1', 'Ma', '1', 'N2', '1', 'O', '1', 'O2', '1', 'OH', '1', 'Points_Magnitude', '1', 'Points_X', '1', 'Points_Y', '1', 'Points_Z', '1', 'Qdot', '1', 'T', '1', 'U_Magnitude', '1', 'U_X', '1', 'U_Y', '1', 'U_Z', '1', 'alphat', '1', 'arc_length', '1', 'cellID', '1', 'k', '1', 'nut', '1', 'omega', '1', 'p', '1', 'rho', '1', 'vtkValidPointMask', '1']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesLineThickness = ['AR', '2', 'H', '2', 'H2', '2', 'H2O', '2', 'H2O2', '2', 'HO2', '2', 'Ma', '2', 'N2', '2', 'O', '2', 'O2', '2', 'OH', '2', 'Points_Magnitude', '2', 'Points_X', '2', 'Points_Y', '2', 'Points_Z', '2', 'Qdot', '2', 'T', '2', 'U_Magnitude', '2', 'U_X', '2', 'U_Y', '2', 'U_Z', '2', 'alphat', '2', 'arc_length', '2', 'cellID', '2', 'k', '2', 'nut', '2', 'omega', '2', 'p', '2', 'rho', '2', 'vtkValidPointMask', '2']
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesMarkerStyle = ['AR', '0', 'H', '0', 'H2', '0', 'H2O', '0', 'H2O2', '0', 'HO2', '0', 'Ma', '0', 'N2', '0', 'O', '0', 'O2', '0', 'OH', '0', 'Points_Magnitude', '0', 'Points_X', '0', 'Points_Y', '0', 'Points_Z', '0', 'Qdot', '0', 'T', '0', 'U_Magnitude', '0', 'U_X', '0', 'U_Y', '0', 'U_Z', '0', 'alphat', '0', 'arc_length', '0', 'cellID', '0', 'k', '0', 'nut', '0', 'omega', '0', 'p', '0', 'rho', '0', 'vtkValidPointMask', '0']

# Properties modified on plotOverLine1Display_1
plotOverLine1Display_1.SeriesVisibility = ['rho']

# save data
SaveData('/media/skumar/Official/OF/SK/grids/testing/'+i+'/plot1.csv', proxy=plotOverLine1)

#### saving camera placements for all active views

# current camera placement for renderView1
renderView1.CameraPosition = [0.10000000149011612, 0.022600000258535147, 0.40111610935790637]
renderView1.CameraFocalPoint = [0.10000000149011612, 0.022600000258535147, 0.0005000000237487257]
renderView1.CameraParallelScale = 0.10368707887055373

#### uncomment the following to render all views
# RenderAllViews()
# alternatively, if you want to write images, you can use SaveScreenshot(...).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `for` loop is badly formed, you are creating three readers in the same variable and then use it.

Put your whole pipeline in the loop